# SSE Client request which does not terminate c#

Tags: c#, http, server-sent-events

I am using C# to connect to a web service. I am need to send a GET request to monitor some transactions, and the web service will be sending the transactions to me continuously without breaking the connection. The web service provider said I need to connect to them with a http library that supports SSE.

I have tried using HttpWebRequest and HttpClient to send request and receive response, but both of my attempt failed. I don't get response from the web service.

My question is:
The web service will send the transactions to me without breaking the connection, but how do I keep the connection up? Do I have to set up a socket for listen after I send the GET request?

Thank you,
kab

Comment: You sure he didn't mean SSL ?

Comment: He said "Basically SSE client request - simple GET request, but that's never ends."

Comment: Check this tutorial for using WebClient to process SSE, http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/c-client-for-server-side-event.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the issue resolved. So basically, I send a httpclient request, then I tie the response stream to an event handler, so whenever there is data on the stream, the event will be raised.

Thanks for all of your inputs.
kab