# how do i receive push notification from URL in desktop .net application? How do i observe a response from URL

Tags: .net, url, push-notification, observer-pattern, couchbase-sync-gateway

**Explanation:**
Couchbase sync gateway provides changes feed sort of push notification, which basically emits change it receives. 
Url is looks like

localhost:4984/db/_changes?style=main_only&active_only=false&include_docs=true&doc_ids=1212&feed=normal&filter=_doc_ids

In simple terms This keep connection open between client(browser) and server(Sync gateway) and as soon as new changes are received, it notify browser the with change.

**Question :**  I have been trying to make a .net Desktop app so i can display the changes what are being received from URL, Instead of using browser, I want to use desktop app.

Changes that are being received we would like to log/validate/transfer to some third party system.

I have tried node JS, it works; however, I could not find any approach where i can implement this in .net.

I have tried Signal R client but it has limitation and does not work.

I am trying to make a solution around observer pattern; how do i observe a URL response?  Polling is not an option otherwise i would have implemented the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try with this .. seems work fine.. thanks for the suggestion, this is very raw code i need to refine it for production ready.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, true))
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, API_URL);
                try
                {
                    using (var response = client.SendAsync(
                    request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result) 
                    {
                        using (var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(body))
                            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating a http connection to the url and then read for changes in the stream.

I will update with an example soon.

Reference
[SSE Client request which does not terminate c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297272/sse-client-request-which-does-not-terminate-c-sharp)

Comment: See also: https://gist.github.com/dmiddlecamp/b698292a5f579e8d288c#file-serversenteventsclient-cs-L80